# o Que devo Estudar?

Tags: android

queria fazer um aplicativo para android onde eu possa mandar um foto e todo mundo que tiver esse aplicativo ter acesso a essa foto e poder avalia-la com uma nota queria, minha duvida é o que devo estudar para conseguir fazer um app assim.Obrigado

ps:eu já fiz um aplicativo para android, uma calculadora de matrizes.

Comment: Estude Java primeiro e depois pegue um livro de Android. Quando tiver dúvidas mais específicas, é bem-vindo a voltar aqui e publicá-las.

Comment: blz, muito obrigado!

Comment: Infelizmente é uma pergunta complicada, pois tem mil maneiras diferentes de se fazer o que você quer. Divida o problema em etapas independentes, e resolva cada uma separadamente. Exemplo: como tirar uma foto com o aplicativo, como enviar e receber dados para o seu sistema, como os terceiros vão acessar as fotos do seu sistema, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Vou dar o exemplo de uma possível forma de fazer, para você ter uma ideia do que precisará aprender (além do básico do Java e do Android):

As fotos e suas respectivas notas precisam ficar guardadas em algum lugar. Geralmente em tabelas de um **banco de dados** (MySQL ou PostgreSQL, para citar dois dos mais populares e gratuitos). Isso envolve aprender o básico da **linguagem SQL**.

(Em vez de guardar diretamente os dados binários que representam a foto num campo do tipo BLOB, você pode alternativamente guardar essas fotos em arquivos e guardar os caminhos desses arquivos na tabela do banco de dados. Você quem escolhe).

O banco de dados costuma ficar em uma máquina remota conectada à Internet e denominada **servidor**. Você poderia acessar as tabelas diretamente a partir do celular mas essa não é a forma correta de fazer; o mais correto é o celular chamar Web Services, que são basicamente URLs que ao serem chamadas executam código no servidor que acessa o banco de dados e retornam esses dados na própria resposta do Web Service. Então estão aí mais algumas coisas para estudar: **Web Services** (e também o básico do protocolo **HTTP**, se quiser saber como eles funcionam por debaixo dos panos) e uma linguagem de programação para escrever esses Web Services, que pode ser o próprio **Java**, caso você não queira estudar PHP, Javascript ou alguma outra.

(Alguns detalhes adicionais: esses Web Services rodam em um ambiente chamado de **servidor de aplicações**, que no caso do Java pode ser por exemplo o **Tomcat**. O servidor de aplicações pode ficar na própria máquina "servidor" que eu falei anteriormente e onde fica também o banco. Como vivemos em tempos de nuvem, há vários serviços gratuitos que permitem a você criar uma máquina remota (virtual) onde pode rodar um servidor de aplicações e um banco de dados sem nenhum custo. Quanto a escrever os Web Services, eu não tenho muita experiência em criá-los com ferramentas, acho que o pessoal costuma usar algo chamado **JAX-RS**. E para o código do Web Service se comunicar com o banco, será usado **JDBC**. Ah, e para transmitir pequenas organizações de dados pelo Web Service, por exemplo as notas de uma foto, é bom você estudar o formato de dados **JSON**).

No Android, para chamar Web Services, você precisará estudar **AsyncTasks**, para que seu aplicativo não trave a tela enquanto chama o Web Service, que por sua vez pode ser chamado usando uma biblioteca como por exemplo a **OkHttp** da Square. E, caso o celular tire fotos muito grandes que ocupam muita memória do aparelho (memória RAM, não memória de armazenamento) e também por questão de reduzir o volume de dados a transmitir, você terá que aprender como reduzir o tamanho dos **Bitmaps** que contêm as fotos antes de transmiti-las.